# How to add a dictionary keys and values to specific columns in an empty dataframe

Tags: pandas, dictionary, append, numpy-ndarray

I have a dict with 3 keys, and each value is a list of numpy arrays.

I'd like to to append this dictionary to an empty dataframe so that the values of the numpy arrays in the list will be the first numbers(column 'x'), the values at the second position in the numpy arrays(column 'y'), and the keys to be the final column (column 'z'), like so:

```
my_dict = {0: [array([5.4, 3.9, 1.3, 0.4]), array([4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2]),array([4.6, 3.6, 1. , 0.2]), array([4.6, 3.2, 1.4, 0.2]), array([4.7, 3.2, 1.6, 0.2])],
1: [array([6.1, 2.9, 4.7, 1.4]), array([5.9, 3. , 4.2, 1.5]), array([7.4, 2.8, 6.1, 1.9])],
2: [array([7. , 3.2, 4.7, 1.4]), array([5.6, 2.7, 4.2, 1.3])]}
```

I'd like to get the below df:

```
     x     y   z
0  5.4   3.9   0
1  4.9   3.    0
2  4.6   3.6   0
3  4.6   3.2   0
4  4.7   3.2   0
5  6.1   2.9   1
6  5.9   3.    1
7  7.4   2.8   1
8  7.    3.2   2
9  5.6   2.7   2
```

it's a bit tricky, how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
data = [j[:2].tolist() + [k] for k, v in my_dict.items() for j in v]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list('xyz')) 

df

     x    y  z
0  5.4  3.9  0
1  4.9  3.0  0
2  4.6  3.6  0
3  4.6  3.2  0
4  4.7  3.2  0
5  6.1  2.9  1
6  5.9  3.0  1
7  7.4  2.8  1
8  7.0  3.2  2
9  5.6  2.7  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
target_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y','z'])  # empty dataframe

for k,v in my_dict.items():
    for val in v:
        d={'x':[val[0]], 'y':[val[1]], 'z':[k]}
        target_df=pd.concat([target_df, pd.DataFrame(d)], ignore_index=True)
```

`print(target_df)` will give desired dataframe

```
     x    y  z
0  5.4  3.9  0
1  4.9  3.0  0
2  4.6  3.6  0
3  4.6  3.2  0
4  4.7  3.2  0
5  6.1  2.9  1
6  5.9  3.0  1
7  7.4  2.8  1
8  7.0  3.2  2
9  5.6  2.7  2
```